# Entity Framework with existing database

Tags: entity-framework

I'm looking to implement entity framework version 4.3.1 in my existing project which don't follow this EF.The database is already developed and is currently used applying ado.net.In this case how do I start with to work on EF, is it Database First,Code first.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Even when a database already exists I still use the Code First approach, mapping the tables using annotations, because the domain is way more organized than on the EDMX file. If there are many tables the visual EDMX can become really useless since the design will be overcrowded with data and connections all over the place.

In two steps you can begin with this approach:

1) Create a domain model class, `Customer` for example, and map it to your table using data annotations:

```
[Table("tbl_cust")]
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    [Column("cust_id")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [Column("cust_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Add other properties below
 }
```

2) Create a context class deriving from `DbContext` and set `DbSet<T>` properties for each model, we have only one in our case so:

```
public class MyApplicationContext: DbContext
{
    public MyApplicationContext() : base("name=ConnectionStringName") { }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

Now anywhere in your code can instantiate the derived `DbContext` class and make queries using Linq:

```
var _db = new MyApplicationContext();
var customer = _db.Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerId == 37).FirstOrDefault();
```

Don't forget to add a reference to EntityFramework assembly using NuGet.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks to all for the awesome solution.I guess I need to go with Database first even if I'm interested in using Code first through Reverse Engineer code first.I tried Code first but no luck it din't create the EF classes and failed maybe my database was't designed very well.Any other reason for the failure?

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't create EF classes" ?

Comment: by EF Classes I mean to say Domain classes for the tables,the models folder.I don't see any populated after I did the reverse engineer code first.I was following this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx

Comment: Don't use reverse engineering, it will create the classes for you, try to use the method I presented above, create the classes yourself. Begin with a single entity and mek it work, then proceed to the others.

Comment: Thanks Anderson.I'll do as you suggested.

Comment: Do not forget `Database.SetInitializer<MyApplicationContext>(null)`

Answer (score 1):

Since your database already exists the obvious choice is Database first. If the database is designed with common sense it (mostly) works great.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is if you want to use the EF Designer to visualize your database or not. Since you are looking at EF 4.3.1 (in fact you should be looking at EF5 not 4.3.1 - EF5 is the latest version) I assume you don't care about the designer. In this case you could use EF Power Tools to reverse engineer your database. This will create a set of classes that will match your database. Note that since the database has already been created EF will not be able to detect changes in your classes (as opposed to databases created by Code First when additional information is stored in the database and EF is able to tell whether the model has changed). Make sure to read this [blog post](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/26/dont-use-code-first-by-mistake/) - it contains a lot of details you may find helpful to make the decision.
If you care about being able to see your model in the designer you can just use VS to reverse engineer DB. If you use VS2012 you will by default get EF5 and DBContext. The difference from using Code First will be that instead of building the model EF needs based on your classes the model is saved in the the edmx file that is part of your project (and used to generate code for you)